# Why my reputation doesn't increased on an answer upvote

Tags: bug, reputation

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224505/1046-no-database-selected?answertab=votes#tab-top) a few hours ago.

I saw an upvote on my answer, but there was no change in reputation.

Is it a bug?

My reputation was `912 points` and even after the upvote it is same.

I didn't get any downvote there

I earned 20 reputation in today morning. so it is not matter of limit capping.

If this is a bug, where do I find help correcting my reputation?

Comment: Your post is Community Wiki; you don't get reputation for such posts.

Comment: Dear god the people who approved the last suggested edit on that post need a beating http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4245522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer was made as community wiki.After a post made as community wiki, upvotes and downvotes won't be calculated.

[image]

Comment: many many thanks bruv